# Python - CGI - (_urandom(16)), 16) WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied

Tags: python, iis-7, cgi

Running this simple script for testing CGI setup.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

#import cgi
print "Content-Type: text/plain\n\n"

gender = "female"

def display_vars (first_name, last_name, age):
    print (first_name, last_name, age, gender)

def go_display():
    gender = "male"
    display_vars("John", "Smith", 22)

go_display()
```

It works and displays `"('John', 'Smith', 22, 'female')"`

change the above from `#import cgi` to `import cgi`

and it fails.

```
The specified CGI application misbehaved by not returning a complete set of HTTP headers. 

(_urandom(16)), 16) WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied
```

Comment: http://forums.iis.net/t/1192084.aspx/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In random.py section-_urandom set except NotImplementedError: to  except:

This works for me.
If you have another answer please let me know and I will try that too.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
print "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\n";
```

Before the content type header.
You should Google your error message.
You would have found this:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/145661

And also this:

http://forums.iis.net/t/1192084.aspx/1

Comment: Same error using print "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\n" and the load user profile to true in application pool's advanced settings was already set to true.